# Any way to make a microsite page private?

Tags: marketing-cloud, microsites

Basically, I do not want anyone to be able to access my microsite page. I only want salesforce marketing cloud users to be able to access the microsite.

So, if anyone tried to access the microsite page by going to the URL, they should get a login screen that requires marketing cloud login credential.

Is this feasible?

Comment: Quick thought, check the referrer header to see if it is coming from an appropriate url or if it is blank and a direct hit... - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: What if a salesforce marketing cloud user wants to directly access ther microsite page? For checking the referrer, I will have to create a separate webpage (or microsite page). Now, what if that page somehow can be access by public outside the organization? In that case this referrer logic won't secure the page from outside traffic.

Comment: The use oAuth or similar. If the marketing cloud user can hit the link directly then you cannot security it from others without a way to identify the user....You cannot have it both ways..

Comment: In salesforce marketing cloud, microsite propertied, there is an option- Security (Dropdown): System Authenticated Redirection. What is the use of this option?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the microsite page, select "System Authenticated Redirection" in the Security dropdown menu :

It redirects to the login page if the visitor is not connected to his SFMC account.

Comment: When I select "System Authenticated Redirection" and try to visit the microsite, the site keeps asking me to login / activate browser. When I activate the browser, it throws an error message saying "An error occurred while sending you the Device Activation Email.  Please contact your account representative if the problem continues."